# Using multiple stores - how can I add a class name in the body or html tags for each website name?

Tags: multistore

I'm using multistore and I have 2 website names. They are all using the same design package, so they share the same css file and template files, layout files etc.

I just need to add a class name in the body or html tag, a different one for each store.

So for example, for website 1:

```
<body class="website1">
```

and website 2:

```
<body class="website2">
```

I thought there might have been an option to add a class name for each website name in admin by either going to `system>config>manage-stores` and adding a class for each website or `system>config>design` then adding a class name for each website by changing the Current Configuration Scope. But looks like I have to do it by using the `local.xml file`. Is it possible to do it from the one local.xml file too, because both stores use the same local.xml file. Can anyone help me with it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento body class has been render from function  `getBodyClass()` of  class `Mage_Page_Block_Html` and a for add a `new body` class,you need to use  `addBodyClass($classname)`.

Now using  `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event/observer, you can add new class to body,because **of after the layout block generate the  addBodyClass() has been works**.

**Xml:**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
      <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento62889/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>addbodyClass</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**and Observer code is**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento62889_Model_Observer
{

            public function addbodyClass(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $root = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
                if ($root) {
                    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
                    $websitecode = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode();
                    $root->addBodyClass($websitecode);
                }

            }

}
```